# why does Redux custom middleware not have access to store's getState and dispatch?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, middleware

There appears to be an issue when I am writing custom middleware that I do not have access to the store. Has anyone else had this issue?

```
   // custom middleware 
   const API = ({ getState, dispatch }) => next => action => {
      console.log(getState); // undefined
      console.log(dispatch); // undefined

      fetch('http://localhost:3000/')
        .then(response => {
          const { ok, status } = rawRes;
        })
        .catch(err => console.error('There appears to be an error in the API Client.', err));

      return next(action);
    };

    export default API;

// creating the store
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import logger from 'redux-logger';

import API from './middlewares/API';

import Reducer from './reducers/index';

const Store = createStore(Reducer, applyMiddleware(
    logger,
    API
  ));

export default Store;
```

I also pass the store to my provider and then I "connect" one of my child components so I can actually dispatch an action. However, when it hits my middleware the store is missing, but action and next seem to be there. I cannot figure out why. Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: tested your code and it seems to work. Can you replace `{ getState, dispatch }` with `store` and console.log it

Comment: @TzookBarNoy I have tried using store as well, and it is also undefined.

Comment: mo idea :| try using without logger and share more of your code..